# Django URL syntax error

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I am creating a wiki app. And when I create url for my app in urls.py I get syntax error message. I am not good at regular expressions.

Here is my code,

```
(r'wikicamp/(?<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'wikicamp.wiki.views.edit_page'),
(r'wikicamp/(?<page_name>[^/]+)/save/$', 'wikicamp.wiki.views.save_page'),
(r'wikicamp/(?<page_name>[^/]+)/$', 'wikicamp.wiki.views.view_page'),
```

And my error is,

```
error at /
syntax error
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.2.5
Exception Type: error
Exception Value:    
syntax error
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.6/re.py in _compile, line 245
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    ['/home/ztron/wikicamp', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
Server time:    Wed, 13 Apr 2011 15:21:18 -0500
```

Is there anything wrong in the regular expression? I did read django documentation but still have no idea.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your named capture groups are missing the 'P'. Do it like so:

```py
(r'wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'wikicamp.wiki.views.edit_page'),
(r'wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/save/$', 'wikicamp.wiki.views.save_page'),
(r'wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/$', 'wikicamp.wiki.views.view_page'),
```

Comment: The P is a python specific bit of syntax that indicates that this is "python named group", as I recall.

Comment: @Soviut: You can use this syntax with PHP as well (and any other tool which uses the excellent [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/ "by Philip Hazel") library).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.python.org/library/re.html the syntax for named groups is

```
(?P<name>...)
```

That means you should have

```
(r'wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$', 'wikicamp.wiki.views.edit_page'),
```